# Activity is not assignable to Activity

Tags: java, android

I have read several posts for the last couple of days and i can not seem to figure out what my issue is. I have checked the Activity names and they are the same. I have also checked my manifest and I have the `.` in front of the activities as well.

Here is my logcat file:

```
02-23 16:48:22.438    1508-1508/com.pctoolman.planme.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL   
         EXCEPTION: main
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     
         ComponentInfo{com.pctoolman.planme.app/com.pctoolman.planme.app.PlanMeMainActivity}:
         java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pctoolman.planme.app.PlanMeMainActivity cannot be 
         cast 
         to android.app.Activity
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pctoolman.planme.app.PlanMeMainActivity 
         cannot
         be cast to android.app.Activity
         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pctoolman.planme.app" >
        <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
                android:name="com.pctoolman.planme.app.PlanMeMainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.pctoolman.planme.app.NewEventSetupActivity"
            android:label="@string/setup">
    </activity>
</application>
```

`PlanMeMainFragment.java`

```
package com.pctoolman.planme.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PlanMeMainFragment extends Fragment {

private Button mNewButton, mExistingButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planme_main_fragment, parent, false);

        mNewButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.new_event_button);
        mNewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewEventSetupActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        return  v;
    }
}
```

`PlanMeMainActivity.java`

```
package com.pctoolman.planme.app;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PlanMeMainActivity extends Fragment {

    public Fragment createFragment() {
        return new PlanMeMainFragment();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your "activity" is really a `Fragment` (you extend fragment). You need to extend `Activity`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change this line

```
public class PlanMeMainActivity extends Fragment {
```

to

```
public class PlanMeMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) you can find all that you need to know about Activities and even more. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

**Where are you wrong?**

```
  <activity
          android:name="com.pctoolman.planme.app.PlanMeMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Why are you wrong?**

> The mistake is that you added the Fragment in the Manifest as
>   Activity. However Fragments are not activities

**What you should do?**

> You should add the fragment in an activity and then define that activity in the
>   Manifest

Comment: Sort of right, but he does have separate `Fragment` and `Activity` classes; he wasn't just adding `PlanMeMainFragment` as his main activity.

Answer (score 2):

Your `PlanMeMainActivity` *isn't an `Activity`*; it's a `Fragment`. Your activity needs to be an activity, and you can then add fragments to it.

Answer (score 2):

Clean Project solved this error. The root cause of the error in my case was different, but I got the same "Activity is not assignable to Activity" error.

I faced this problem after copying existing (perfectly working) Android Project to create a new one. 
After copying the project, the AppCompatActivity was not recognized causing all the activities in the Android Manifest file to show the error "activity-is-not-assignable-to-activity".
Which was solved by cleaning the project.

Answer (score 1):

Your PlanMainActivity extends a Fragment. A fragment cannot be cast to an activity

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find out the solution is add following line in your dependencies:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'`

Answer (score 1):

just delete ".gradle" folder of your project
and press sync button .
its solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was occurred by just installed plugin in Android Studio. So check your plugins and uninstall odd ones.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by Invalidating Caches and Restarting after having Cleaned the Project.

Comment: Invalidating Caches seems like a good answer and is what worked for me.